# Copy a Queue in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, queue

I need a copy of the current state of a [Queue](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) object to perform another operation on its contents. I don't want to disturb the original queue, just copy it and then empty it out as I run my thread on it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [#dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) or [#clone](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-clone)? I'm not sure if you'll need a mutex around the actual copy or not, but it's a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the deep_dive gem.

Also, check out the queue_ding gem, as it can do a tee, thus eliminating the need for you to copy the queue. The tee must be in a different thread, though.